# Select an element from multiple classes

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to select some `<img>` from my page with different sections and give it a `width` of 80% of its container. 
I realized my code only selects the `<img>` element from `.things-love` class!
Is there a way I can select all the sections with classes I want changes to apply with `<img>` element?

```
.about-me, .education, .skills, .experience, .things-love img{
    width: 80%
}
```

Comment: `.about-me, .education, .skills, .experience, img{
    width: 80%
}` if you noticed, I removed `.things-love` from your code. that should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 2021 update:

Most browsers now support `:is()` pseudo-class. This lets us express the same selector more succinctly:

```css
:is(.about-me, .education, .skills, .experience, .things-love) img { 
  width: 80% 
}
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is

---

### Old solution

Add `img` after each container like this:

```css
.about-me img, 
.education img, 
.skills img, 
.experience img, 
.things-love img { 
  width: 80% 
}
```

Or add a class to `img`s and target them directly

```html
...
<div class="about-me">
   <img class="container-img" src="...">
</div>
...
```

```css
.container-img {
  width: 70%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.about-me img, .education img, .skills img, .experience img, .things-love img{
    width: 80%
}
```

You have to provide image tag for every class. What you did is you selected the classes for other sections but you have selected image for the **.things-love** class only